# Is it possible to stab an enemy before the hand goes into the ready position?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy

As stated in the title is it possible to stab an enemy before the hand goes into the ready position?

For those who don't know already:

This is the "ready" position that the hand goes into before you stab someone.

[image: Ready]

This is the "idle" position that the hand is in by default.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes - whether or not the hand is in the ready position depends on whether your client thinks you're behind the target. Whether or not you get a backstab depends on whether the server thinks you're behind the target.

It's possible to get a normal stab even though it looked like you should have got a backstab, or to backstab when you think you're going to stab normally.

Answer (score 5):

From the [wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Backstab#Mechanism):

> A Spy may backstab an enemy as long as the enemy is close within standard melee attack range, and the Spy is within a 180° range behind the enemy.

The important aspect is that the server believes the attack was executed within the appropriate range. You need not wait until the raised-hand animation completes (or even begins, for that matter).

[Further down in the article](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Backstab#Issues) you can read about the fine details of the attack (including the notorious facestab and a more precise definition of "within 180° range behind the enemy").